# Python anyway to show the sequence label TCAG in the matrix? Global Alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, bioinformatics

Anyway i can show the label in these in python code?
[image: example]

```
    %matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
plt.imshow(alignment_matrix, cmap='Pastel1')
plt.title("Alignment Matrix", size=30)

tick_marks = np.arange(0)
#plt.xticks(tick_marks, [sequence_1[0], sequence_1[1], sequence_1[2], sequence_1[3]], size=10)
#plt.yticks(tick_marks, [sequence_2[0], sequence_2[1], sequence_2[2], sequence_2[3]], size=10)
plt.xticks(tick_marks)
plt.yticks(tick_marks)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel("Sequence 1", size=20)
plt.ylabel("Sequence 2", size=20)

w, h = alignment_matrix.shape
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        plt.annotate(str(alignment_matrix[x][y]), xy=(y,x), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', size=20)
plt.show()
```

my code will only show the number but without labels[image: output]

The sequence is read from a txt file, and assign into string value.
[image: sequence assign]

The link to this code : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXoB8zWUvwyCViORIKesjrkmj7VVOvOE/view?usp=sharing